# android menu in fragment not reaload

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity (AppCompatActivity) (called Activity) and two fragments (called Fragment A and Fragment B).

When Activity is lunched, I use `setContentView` and Fragment A was generated.

When I try to start Activity with specific parameter I lunch Fragment B.
Fragment A and Fragment B has the same layout, I change only the data to be rendered.

In Fragment A, I have a menu with 1 item, this one performs an action on my view: change list to a grid layout.

In fragment B, I have this menu too, but, when I click on the item nothing changes. So I've tried this in debug mode. I've seen that when I press item in the menu, for Fragment B, this called menu action of Fragment A.

How can I resolve this cycle?

Comment: I can help you, post your code here, this may help: do not call super from onCreateOptionsMenu in your fragments

Comment: I'll suggest you to override OnCreateOptionsMenu() method in both Fragment and handle on both places from Fragment instead of Activity.

Comment: When you say "When I try to start Activity with specific parameter I lunch Fragment B", does that mean that you launch **both** Fragment A and Fragment B, or **only** Fragment B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select a menu item, the system will dispatch that event to the active `Activity` as well as all currently active `Fragment`s. The event will be dispatched to the Fragments in the order they were added to the Activity.

If **Fragment A** and **Fragment B** both include an `onOptionsItemSelected()` implementation that handles the same `R.id` constant, this will cause the problem you're seeing.

For example, imagine Fragment A has this code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_settings) {
        // do some Fragment A thing
    }
    ...
}
```

And imagine Fragment B has this code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_settings) {
        // do some Fragment B thing
    }
    ...
}
```

Even if the user clicks on `R.id.action_settings` inside Fragment B, the system will dispatch the event to Fragment A, and Fragment A will happily handle it!

There are a few different solutions to this problem.

First, you could change your menus in your two fragments so that they have the same text labels but use different `android:id` attributes (and then update your Fragment code accordingly). Now only the "right" fragment will be able to handle the item selection event.

Second, you could update your `onOptionsItemSelected()` code to determine whether the Fragment is currently active, and ignore the event if it is not:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (!isAdded() || !isVisible()) {
        return false;
    }

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_settings) {
        // do some Fragment A thing
    }
}
```

Finally, you could use dynamically-generated IDs for your menu items. I'd recommend against this approach as it is much more complicated than the others.